# Does rm -r follow symbolic links?

Tags: bash, unix

If I have symbolic links in some subtree of my directories and decide to recursively removed a driectory and its contents, will that remove items symbolically linked in the tree?

Comment: Belongs on [su].

Comment: Doesn't really need to be on Super User; it is a question about a program used in shell programming, and as such is on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Read the manual, do some experiments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does rm -rf follow symbolic links?](https://superuser.com/questions/382314/does-rm-rf-follow-symbolic-links) (historical note: this question was originally on SO, then got migrated here. the answer post linked to the dup-target I'm proposing)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the man file

```
$ man rm

...
The rm utility removes symbolic links, not the files referenced by the links.
...
```

Version OS X 10.8.2

Look this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/382314/does-rm-f-follow-symbolic-links).